# How to match any occurrence of a character except if it occurs two times?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match any occurrence of the plus sign at the end of a term, except if it is occurring exactly two times. For example, the plus signs in `c+` and `c++++` should be matched, but **not** in `c++`.

The naive approach `\+{1}$|\+{3,}$` does not work, obviously. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Apply a lookahead to the first to check there is no `+` before: `(?<!\+)\+$`

Comment: @SebastianProske `(?<!` it is look behind.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Yep, my brain is in end of work mode.

Comment: @SebastianProske Your solution is working, but I cannot accept your answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regex using a negative lookahead:

```
\b\+(?:\+{2,})?(?!\+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijrhvW/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b` - Assert a Word boundary
- `\+` - Match literal `+`
- `(?:\+{2,})?` - Optionally match 2 or more `+`
- `(?!\+)` - Negative lookahead to ensure there is no `+` ahead to block `++`

Comment: I only needed to match the plus signs, so I am going to accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I like building my regex here: [regex builder](http://regexr.com/)
Looks like this one will grab c+, not c++, and c with 3 or more + signs

```
(c\+{1}|(\+){3,})
```

Answer (score 0):

`^[^+]*(?:\+|[+]{3,})$` will match your contrived example as well as anything in the position of `c` in your contrived example.